# Subset data frame that contains value from array

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   114034 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Ore     : chr  "01 00" "01 01" "01 02" "01 03" ...
 $ SquareID: chr  "10000" "10000" "10000" "10000" ...
 $ Intens  : num  0.0118 0.00987 0.00538 0.01318 0.00273 ...
 $ Count   : num  69 78 51 86 35 ...
```

I need to subset the entire dataframe. the row of the dataframe where  SquareID are equal to those Array values.

```
Df<-subset.data.frame(Df,Df$SquareID==c(4702,4703,4704,4705,5434,5435,4706,4707,4708,4709,4820,4939,4821,4822,5551,5057,4823,5058,4824,4825,5059,4826,5174,4940,4941,5175,4942,4943,5177,5178,4944,5060,4945,5061,4946,5062,5063,4728,5295,5296,5297,5180,5181,4845,4846,4847,4963,4964,5199,4353,5082,4355,4356,4585,9536,4586,4587,4470,4588,4471,4589,4472,4473,5412,5413,5414,9653,4590,4591,5530,5315,5316,5318)
```

In this way I got this warning and wrong result:

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: See the helpfile `?"%in%"`.

Comment: I need to subset the entire dataframe, I don't need a vector as result

Comment: Right, `subset(Df, SquareID %in% c(...))`. Your `SquareID` column is `character` though so you should convert it to `numeric` first.

Comment: Daniele0 look at the warning from `1:2 == 1:3`. It's the same as you get above

Comment: @nrussel thanks, write it as answer if you want rep .

Answer (score 1):

nrussell is right.
Say you have a dataframe

```
> df <- data.frame(SquareId = c("1","2","3","4"), Intens = c(15,30,45,60))
> df
  SquareId Intens
1        1     15
2        2     30
3        3     45
4        4     60
```

you can subset it like this:

```
> df <- subset(df, SquareId %in% c("2","3"))
> df
  SquareId Intens
2        2     30
3        3     45
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the logical comparison in the line:

```
Df<-subset.data.frame(Df,Df$SquareID==c(4702,4....))
```

`Df$SquareID` is a vector of length 114034 (the number of rows of the dataframe), while `c(4702,4....)` is a vector of length 73, therefor `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. You need %in% as nrussell suggested.

```
 Df<-subset(Df,Df$SquareID %in% c(4702,4....))
```